# Change Wi-Fi country/region on Synology RT2600ac

Tags: wireless-networking, synology

I bought a Synology RT2600ac router in the US and brought it to Germany. The router is configured with the region as the US, which is of course now wrong. The configuration UI has no way to change it. It's easy to SSH into the router as root, but I haven't seen anywhere to change the region.

Many search results suggest using `iw reg set XX`, but all `iw` commands give me `nl80211 not found` which is either a defect in the firmware or an intentional omission.

The best I've managed is using `iwpriv` to turn off broadcast of the country code, but that won't fix issues like the channels, DFS, and transmit power all being wrong, and it doesn't persist through reboots.

I've edited a bunch of files in `/usr/syno/etc/wifi/` but none seem to have any effect.

Comment: What you want might not be possible there is a push to force regionalization restrictions within the chips themselves

Answer (score 1):

Online, it shows that you can select a new country while you configure the router for the first time.  I would suggest conducting a factory reset (hidden reset button on the router) and reconfiguring the router from scratch.

[image]

Comment: Sadly the country option isn't there for mine. I guess they removed it. Maybe if I downgrade the firmware...

Comment: Update: Can't downgrade it, at least not using the standard methods. Might require some hackery or just binning this and getting Ubiquiti hardware as I should have done from the beginning.

Comment: Or just keep using it as it is because the region is really not a problem considering the main difference is the absence of a couple of channels in the US.